# Flutter press suffixIcon without entring the text form field

Tags: flutter

I have a TextFormField of a password and I want to put a suffixIcon so when the user press the icon the obsecure getting change and it's working but it's also entering me to the textform field and open the keyboard and I dont want that, Someone know how to do that?
this is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'

class trying extends StatefulWidget {
  const trying({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _tryingState createState() => _tryingState();
}

class _tryingState extends State<trying> {
  
  bool _secureText = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    void secureText() {
      setState(() {
        _secureText = !_secureText;
      });
    }

    return Container(
      child: TextFormField(
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: size.width * .040,
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Password',
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              secureText();
            },
            icon: Icon(
              _secureText ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        obscureText: _secureText,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe you can use `FocusNode` to unfocus the keyboard when you press the icon

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to unfocus keyboard when u click the icon like

```
onPressed: () {
    secureText();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made small change,also don't put your _secureText() function under the Widget,also try use different names for function,it helps to identify fast using same name create confusion

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 

  bool _secureText = false;

   void _togglevisibility() {
    setState(() {
      _secureText = !_secureText;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  return TextFormField(
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: size.width * .040,
    ),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Password',
      suffixIcon: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
         _togglevisibility();
        },
        icon: Icon(
          _secureText ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    obscureText: !_secureText,
  );
  }
}
```